# Using a Dictionary<TKey, TValue> with Exceptions

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

I'm trying to figure out how I can save Exceptions within a dictionary in c#.

**For example, I try:**

```
Dictionary<Exception, Exception> myCustomExceptions = new() 
{
    { DbUpdateException, CustomExceptionX },
    { InvalidOperationException, CustomExceptionY }
}
```

**Then I try to do something like this:**

```
try
{
    ...
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    throw myExceptions[exception];
}
```

But this however does not work unfortunately... Can someone please help me with this particular issue?

Comment: You would need to store types of exceptions in your dictionary, not exception objects, e.g. `typeof(DbUpdateException)`. Then, in your `catch` block, you can call `GetType` on the exception and use the result as a key into the dictionary. There will be more to it than that, because you've still got to create the new exception to throw, but that's a start. Note also that you probably ought to assign the original exception as the `InnerException` of the new one, but there might be an explicit reason that you don't want to do that.

Comment: ... also value should be instance of exception then ...

Comment: Side note for future questions: Don't just say "but this doesn't work", you have to explain like "I was expecting X but I'm getting Y" or "this is throwing the follow exception:<exception message>". Doesn't work is too broad and can mean a lot of things.

Comment: Thank you everyone, you all helped me with this. In the future I will try to be more clear of what I actually was expecting indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to store a factory which can make new exception instances on demand.

```cs
Dictionary<Type, Func<Exception>> myCustomExceptions = new() 
{
    { typeof(DbUpdateException), () => new CustomExceptionX() },
    { typeof(InvalidOperationException), () => new CustomExceptionY() }
}

try
{
    ...
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    var exceptionType = exception.GetType();
    var factory = myExceptions[exceptionType];
    var ex = factory();
    throw ex;
}
```

Comment: Tangential side note: It could probably be of benefit in certain troubleshooting scenarios to have the original exception instance as InnerException of the newly created exception. (It would of course require the custom exception classes to have a constructor overload for passing the inner exception.)

Comment: Oh absolutely -- there's no message either, or any other details. I disagree with the approach taken here, but this is how you do it technically